# matching two dimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach

Guys , I'm trying match two dimensional array. This is the code which demonstrates what I'm doing:

```
$games = array("Game1" => "Team 2 vs. Team 3", "Game2" => "Team 1 vs. Win 1","Game3" => "Loser Game 1 vs. Loser Game 2","Game4" => "Win Game 2 vs. Win Game 3", "Game5" => "Win Game 4 vs. Loser Game 4 (If Loser 4 is First Loss)");

$time= array("06:00 " => "06:30","06:30 " => " 07:00","07:00" => "07:30","07:30" =>"08:00","08:00" => "08:30");

foreach($games as $games => $versus)
{
   foreach($time as $start_time => $end_time)
   {
      echo $games . ": ". $versus ." ". $start_time. " to " . $end_time . "<br>";
   }
}
```

However, this outputs

```
Game1: Team 2 vs. Team 3 = 06:00 to 06:30
Game1: Team 2 vs. Team 3 = 06:30 to 07:00
Game1: Team 2 vs. Team 3 = 07:00 to 07:30
Game1: Team 2 vs. Team 3 = 07:30 to 08:00
Game1: Team 2 vs. Team 3 = 08:00 to 08:30
Game2: Team 1 vs. Win 1 = 06:00 to 06:30
Game2: Team 1 vs. Win 1 = 06:30 to 07:00
Game2: Team 1 vs. Win 1 = 07:00 to 07:30
Game2: Team 1 vs. Win 1 = 07:30 to 08:00
Game2: Team 1 vs. Win 1 = 08:00 to 08:30
Game3: Loser Game 1 vs. Loser Game 2 = 06:00 to 06:30
Game3: Loser Game 1 vs. Loser Game 2 = 06:30 to 07:00
Game3: Loser Game 1 vs. Loser Game 2 = 07:00 to 07:30
Game3: Loser Game 1 vs. Loser Game 2 = 07:30 to 08:00
Game3: Loser Game 1 vs. Loser Game 2 = 08:00 to 08:30
Game4: Win Game 2 vs. Win Game 3 = 06:00 to 06:30
Game4: Win Game 2 vs. Win Game 3 = 06:30 to 07:00
Game4: Win Game 2 vs. Win Game 3 = 07:00 to 07:30
Game4: Win Game 2 vs. Win Game 3 = 07:30 to 08:00
Game4: Win Game 2 vs. Win Game 3 = 08:00 to 08:30
Game5: Win Game 4 vs. Loser Game 4 (If Loser 4 is First Loss) = 06:00 to 06:30
Game5: Win Game 4 vs. Loser Game 4 (If Loser 4 is First Loss) = 06:30 to 07:00
Game5: Win Game 4 vs. Loser Game 4 (If Loser 4 is First Loss) = 07:00 to 07:30
Game5: Win Game 4 vs. Loser Game 4 (If Loser 4 is First Loss) = 07:30 to 08:00
Game5: Win Game 4 vs. Loser Game 4 (If Loser 4 is First Loss) = 08:00 to 08:30
```

and I want to display it like this instead

```
Game1: Team 2 vs. Team 3 06:00 to 06:30
Game2: Team 1 vs. Win 1 06:30 to 07:00
Game3: Loser Game 1 vs. Loser Game 2 07:00 to 07:30
Game4: Win Game 2 vs. Win Game 3 = 07:30 to 08:00
Game5: Win Game 4 vs. Loser Game 4 (If Loser 4 is First Loss) = 08:00 to 08:30
```

How I can solve this ? 
Thank You in Advance who help to me..

Comment: I am not sure if this part is correct: `foreach($games as $games => $versus)` I think it should be `foreach($games as $game => $versus)`

Comment: In order to do what you are trying to do, you need some sort of connection between `$games` and `$time` array which you don't have. You might want to combine them into a singles `$games_time` array.

Comment: I updated my answer .Code will get the results you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have control over the arrays I would go with a different structure where you can easily match the games and times.

But, since you don't have numeric keys you need to get the key `key()` and value `current()` from the `$time` array and advance the array pointer every loop iteration:

```
foreach($games as $game => $versus)
{
    echo $game . ": " . $versus ." ". key($time) ." to ". current($time) ."<br>";
    next($time);
}
```

Actually it might be simpler using `each()`:

```
foreach($games as $game => $versus)
{
    list($start, $end) = each($time);
    echo $game . ": " . $versus ." ". $start ." to ". $end ."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to combine the games and start/end time into one multi-dimensional array if possible (this is just one of the many possible approaches). This example is for 2 games but you can add more to it:

```
$games = array(
    "Game1" => 
            Array(
                "versus" => "Team 2 vs. Team 3",
                "start_time" => "06:00",
                "end_time" => "06:30"
            ),
     "Game2" => 
            Array(
                "versus" => "Team 1 vs. Win 1",
                "start_time" => "06:30",
                "end_time" => "07:00"
            )
);

foreach ($games as $game => $arr)
{
    echo "<br>";
    echo $game . ": versus : " . $arr['versus'] . ": start_time: ";
    echo $arr['start_time'] . ": end_time: " . $arr['end_time'];
}
```

Output:

> Game1: versus : Team 2 vs. Team 3: start_time: 06:00: end_time: 06:30
>
> Game2: versus : Team 1 vs. Win 1: start_time: 06:30: end_time: 07:00

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes I did. This is just another way to do what OP is trying to achieve. It will only work in the case if when it is possible to combine the two arrays into a single multi-dimensional array as I mentioned.

Comment: @RiggsFolly It's okay. If you don't like my answer then just go ahead and downvote it or the OP can downvote it. End of matter. why make an issue out of it.

Comment: Cause its a waste of disk space. If he didnt have the data in such a mess, he probably would not need to ask the question

Comment: Let me pose a similar question and answer: Q= _how do I get to the railway station from here_ A= _I done know but if we were in main street I could give you diections from there_